# Creating Dynamic DELETE asp.net button for each record not using gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have been struggling for a while looking for an answer to this. I have a page that displays records not in a gridview but via styled div's. I have managed to create a button for each record.

```
Imports sc
Imports sq
Imports System.Data

Partial Class _Default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim c As New sc
Dim q As New sq

Public IsAdmin As String = "0"

Private Sub _Default_PreRender(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    c.ReadS(q.IsAdminStr)
    If c.sqldr.Read Then IsAdmin = "1"
    c.con.Close()

    If IsAdmin = "1" Then admin.Visible = True

    c.FillDS(q.CurrStatStr)

    For Each dr As DataRow In c.sqldt.Rows
        systems.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<div class=""system""><table width=""100%""><tr><td width=""50%"" style=color:#00a0d0>"))
        systems.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl(dr("system")))
        systems.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</td><td width=""50%"" align=""right"" style=color:" & dr("colourhex") & ">" & dr("status")))
        systems.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</td></tr>"))
        systems.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</table>"))

        If dr("status").ToString <> "Running" Then
            systems.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<hr><table width=""100%""><tr><td>" & dr("comments") & "</td></tr></table>"))
        End If

        If IsAdmin = "1" Then
            systems.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("<div class=""sysadmin"">"))
            Dim btn As New Button
            btn.CommandArgument = dr("id")
            btn.Text = "Update"
            btn.CssClass = "btn"
            AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf btn_click
            systems.Controls.Add(btn)
            systems.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</div>"))
        End If

        systems.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</div>"))

    Next

End Sub

Public Sub btn_click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btn As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Response.Redirect("Subscribe.aspx?id=" & btn.CommandArgument)
    MsgBox(btn.CommandArgument)
End Sub

End Class
```

I have added the response.redirect just to test it but this is not working. How do i get the buttons that i have added to do anything relating to the ID of the record for the button i pressed.

Hope this makes sense guys.

Thanks in advance. (i apologise if some of this is formatted incorrectly. i am still new to stack overflow.)

Comment: What Type is `systems`?

Comment: Hi Systems is just a div.

    <div ID="systems" runat="server"></div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When databinding you can use the `CommandArgument` property:

```
btn.CommandArgument = id
```

Then in your click event:

```
Response.Redirect("Subscribe.aspx?id=" & btn.CommandArgument)
```

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately nothing happens still when i click the buttons. It just looks to refresh/reload the page.

Comment: Can you confirm btn_Click is being hit? Can you re-bind `Systems` on PostBack?

Comment: How do i confirm that? Also, how do you re-bind a div. sorry. i am still learning.

Comment: Hi mxmissile. i dont think it is. The button simply reloads the page. No matter what i put in the click event it doesnt happen.

Comment: Thank you mxmissile. This combined with moving where the code is actually situated worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I use list(of whatever) this way you manage your controls. Add the new control to the list then add your click handler from your list object. You will have all the items to point to that single function or sub. Then you do like you did with directcast.

What you are doing is reusing the same variable btn where it's  wrong because you are not keeping the object itself to work with. This is why you make a list. Easier to manage than arrays. Make btn a list(of button) a the top of your class. Don't forget to create the list before you can add to it. Btn = new List (of button)

You can set the name of each button to figure out with one goes with what records

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately i am still learning so i am not sure how to do what you have advised.

Comment: if it helps anyone to help me. I have amended question to include the whole code from this page.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have sussed it. It seems to work perfectly with the above code now that i have moved it to the page load event instead of pre render.

Thanks for all your help.